# TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

I'm working on this new AngularJS project with ngStorage (localStorage) and not quite sure why I'm getting the message below. I get this whenever I click on my add button.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined AngularJS
```

Below is my code. Can someone explain why this error is occurring?

```
.factory ('StorageService', function($localStorage) {

$localStorage = $localStorage.$default({
  favorites: []
});

var _getAll = function () {
  return $localStorage.favorites;
}; 

var _add = function (color) {
  $localStorage.favorites.unshift(color);
}
var _remove = function (color) {
  $localStorage.favorites.splice(index, 1);
}
return {
   getAll: _getAll,
    add: _add,
    remove: _remove
  };
})
```

**controller**

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, dataService, StorageService) {

    $scope.add = function (color) {
        StorageService.add(StorageService.favorites.unshift(dataService.colors.indexOf(color)));
        console.log(color);
      };
)};
```

Comment: StorageService has no property called favorites.. add it to the return object.

Comment: It's because localStorage.favorites doesn't exist.

Comment: StorageService exposes only whats returned (getAll, add, remove)

Comment: So would it be something like this: return {
   getAll: _getAll,
    add: _add,
    remove: _remove, StorageService: $localStorage.favorites
  };

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the line in your controller:

`StorageService.add(StorageService.favorites.unshift(dataService.colors.indexOf(color)));`

I assume you want to call the `add` method of your service and pass it the value of `color` in `dataService`.

As metioned in the other answers your error comes from `favorites` not being defined in the return block of your service. But if you do define it you still won't be adding the color since `unshift` will return the new length of `StorageService.favorites`.

If my asumption is correct you'll probably want to do something like:

`StorageService.add(dataService.colors.indexOf(color));`

If you do need to "get" the favorites from your service, don't break your encapsulation by publishing `$localStorage.favorites` but use your `getAll` method to get the "favorites".

P.S. Also don't forget to check that dataService actually has a colors key or you have another potential null-pointer.

Comment: with that line of code I want the user to be able to add a color to 'favorites'. You are correct I'm passing it the value of color in dataService (where all the colors are).

Comment: I'm confused on how I should use getAll now

Comment: You don't need to use getAll in your add method. Just call it as I described. It should work. What I meant to say with the remark about getAll is that you don't need to add favorites to your service as suggested in the comments to your question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was able to resolve my issue by using the getAll method to get the favorites. I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can access the favorites array like this (use the getAll function that is already exposed):

```
    StorageService.add(StorageService.getAll.unshift(dataService.colors.indexOf(color)));
```